# call js function when page load

Tags: javascript, function, call, onload

i have a simple problem but i don't know how solve it.

I have a page(page1.jsp) that have a form and that open another page(page2.jsp) when click on a button.

When page2.jsp is open, i need that it will call a function that is in an external js file.

previously i called this function when user "onchange" on a select.
Now i need that the function will be called automatically at load page2.jsp
I add this code in the  of my page

```
    <head>
    <% 
    String bloccovecchio= request.getParameter("ID");
    %>
    <script>
    window.onload=bloccoSelettivoChangeEvent(request.getParameter("ID"));
    </script>

    </head>
```

i tried also adding this code in the body

```
    <body onload="bloccoSelettivoChangeEvent(<%=bloccovecchio%>)">
```

why this doesn't work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what does your function look like?

Comment: My function seems doesn't call.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function and storing what it returns to be executed onload.

```
window.onload=bloccoSelettivoChangeEvent(request.getParameter("ID"));
```

needs to be

```
window.onload= function () {bloccoSelettivoChangeEvent(request.getParameter("ID")); };
```

better yet, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)